# How to minify and uglify an NPM package written in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, minify, uglifyjs

I need to publish minified version of an NPM package written in Typescript. To compile the app I use `tsc -p .` command and it builds the package in `lib` folder. I feel that `lib` is somewhat similar to `src` folder in terms of size as it has unnecessary folder, sub-folders and files.

Is it possible to minify and uglify this `lib` folder into just a single `index.min.js` file?

**P.S.** this package is a CLI tool. Is there any need to ship type definitions in `d.ts` files? All they contain is just types for functions and variables used in the code.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To merge everything into one file you need to set the [`outFile` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#outFile) in your typescript property

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outFile": "./lib/index.js"
// more configs here
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

For minification you have to use an external tool since Typescript does not have any option for that and maybe it will never have since [it is an open request since 2014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8)

Comment: Won't work since I'm using Common JS module

Comment: But why? If you want everything in one file then you do not need to use any module

Comment: First of all module is not some sort of package but a key in tsconfig. Second, what's the connection b/w the final build file and module? This module is being used just for the sake of enabling import/export statements.